# Projection operator fixed up to a constant

Tags: operator-theory, map-projections

Let $\Omega$ be a polygonal domain in $\mathbb{R}^2$, $V$ a closed and finite dimensional subspace of $H^1(\Omega)$ and $\mathbb{P}_k(\Omega)$ the usual space of polynomials of maximum degree $k$.

I'll define the operator $\Pi : V \to \mathbb{P}_k(\Omega)$ over all the elements $v \in V$ as:

\begin{equation}
\label{eq1}
\tag{1}
\begin{cases}
a(\Pi v, p) = a(v,p) \qquad \forall p \in \mathbb{P}_k(\Omega) \\[6pt]
\displaystyle \int_{\partial \Omega} \Pi v= \int_{\partial \Omega} v
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

where $a(\cdot,\cdot)$ is the $L^2$ inner product of the gradients:
$$a(v,w) := \int_\Omega \nabla v \cdot \nabla w$$

The text I'm reading says that \ref{eq1} defines $\Pi$ only up to a constant, therefore we have to introduce another projection operator $P_0 : V \to \mathbb{P}_0(\Omega) $ to fix that constant requirring for all $v \in V$ to satisfy
$$P_0 (\Pi v − v ) = 0$$

I can't get the need of $P_0$, or better, I can't understand why is there a constant to be fixed. Can anyone help me please?

**EDIT**

added the screenshot of the source where I found the "definition" \ref{eq1}:

[image]

Comment: In $(1)$ we have some $$\int_{\partial\Omega}v$$ and $v$ was never defined. I would suppose it is an element of the "very general" Hilbert space $V$, but what does this Hilbert space has to do with $\Omega$?! Please introduce in a proper manner this $V$, it is maybe some $L^2$ (or Sobolev) space related to $\Omega$, which is possibly some open domain in some $\Bbb R^?$. And please also introduce $\Omega$ previously, so that the reader is not always waiting for stuff to be defined, while digesting the text.

Comment: Updated. Thanks for your suggestion, I was too brief

Comment: I see there is a bounty now on the question... which is the source for the "text" mentioned in the question?

Comment: I'm currently studying Virtual Element Methods, so you can find this operator (usually written as $\Pi^\nabla$) in any of the pubblications about this subject. I'll copy two titles of the main articles: "Basic principles of virtual element methods" and "The Hitchhiker’s Guide to the Virtual Element Method" both published by Mathematical Models and Methods in Applied Sciences or findable online via www.worldscientific.com. PS. The definition I used here is from the second article at page 1548.

Comment: I took a look at http://arturo.imati.cnr.it/brezzi/papers/hitchhikers-preprint.pdf - here in the relation $(3.2)$ i see only the condition $$a(\Pi v-v\ ,\ p)=0\qquad\text{ for all }p\in\mathcal P(E)\ .$$This is compared to the relation $(1)$ from the question only the half of $(1)$. The wording "is defined" (by $(3.2)$) is also irritating seen from where i am looking at - since the next propsition confesses that the "definition" works up to a constant. But as i see, taking the integral as in $(3.4b)$ and using this projector to $\mathcal P_0(E)$ for $\Pi_0$ fixes the freedom...

Comment: So where does your second relation in $(1)$ - explicitly$$\int_{\partial \Omega}(\Pi v-v) = 0$$ come from? Please give a clear reference. Also, it may be good to fix the occurrences of $\Omega$ (which is a union of "pieces" $E$) and $E$ (which appears at only one place, in the definition of $a$) in the question.

Comment: Honestly this had also confused me, I took that "definition" from a presentation the professor gave me (screenshot added to the question). However I don't understand your first comment: (3.4b) is the definition of the projector to the constants so in which sense are you "taking the integral as in (3.4b)"? What I do not understand is how to integrate the first equation of (1) and how $P_0$ fixes the constant we should get.

Comment: Also the fact that $\Omega$ is a union of pieces is not very useful to the question itself. I apologize for the $E$ that I wrongly added in the question. To answer this question the setting I wrote should be enough and adding more and more thing simply confuses people